# What is the appropriate number of memory usage for Windows Phone app

Tags: performance, memory, windows-phone-7

as my title.

I heard that my friend's app was failed to publish to marketplace. Because it consumes more than 90MB phone memory.

I'm developing an application and it uses about 30-60 MB (according to memory counter display from this [link.](http://dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2010/09/27/Debug-Memory-Counter-for-Windows-Phone-7.aspx))

Firstly I thought it was too much for a mobile app. I put all my data entries into memory in order to do search, instead of querying them from SQLite which is too slow for me.

So what do you think about the appropriate number of the phone memory for a regular mobile application.

Comment: +1 for being a mobile developer who cares this much about memory usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, [Microsoft Certification Requirements document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840%28VS.92%29.aspx) says that:

> An application must not exceed 90 MB of RAM usage, except on devices that have more than 256 MB of memory.

If you break this rule, your application won't pass Microsoft certification process.

Comment: And, even if you pass cerificiation, you will be terminated at runtime.